# How to get minor allele frequency?

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a on my Linux machine like this:below.

```
AF.Cases AF.Controls
0.0044 0.00159
0.0018 0.00315
0.3920 0.38898
```

Now I want to get the minor allele frequency (maf).

So, if `AF.Cases` is greater than 0.5, the formula would be

```
1-AF.Cases = MAF
```

So, in summary, the formula can be

```
MAF = min(AF.Cases 1-AF.Cases)
```

In Linux, I cannot extract the maf from the file by the code as below as it said 
"fatal: function `min' not defined"

```
awk 'NR>1{print min($1 1-$1)}' file > outfile
```

Can anybody teach me how to get MAF from the file?

Comment: Can you provide some example input please (just a few lines; doesn't have to be real data but make it plausible). While you're [edit]ing your question, please address "_I cannot extract the maf from the file by the code as below_". Why can't you extract it? What happens? What doesn't happen? Please tell us!

Comment: Could you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/584872/edit) your question to indicate the error message you get when running your `awk` command? Also, note that `awk` is a text processing language, and while some mathematical functions are implemented, I have not yet seen the `min` function (at least in GNU awk). Maybe a perl or python script are more suited for your task if the task turns out to be more than just this "simple" calculation.

Comment: "*So, if AF.Cases is greater than 0.5, the formula would be*" OK, and what would the formula be if AF.Cases is less than 0.5? `min($1, 1-$1)` suggests you want to print `$1` if it is less than `0` and `1-$1` if `$1` is greater than 0. Is that what you want? Remember that users here don't work in bioinformatics, and have no idea what an allele is, let alone what MAF is. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: I want to get whichever minimum, $1 or 1-$1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly use

```
awk 'NR > 1 { maf = ($1 > 0.5 ? 1 - $1 : $1); print maf }' file
```

or just

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print ($1 > 0.5 ? 1 - $1 : $1) }' file
```

Or, using a calculation of the minimum of `$1` and `1 - $1` (there is no `min()` function in `awk`):

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print ($1 < 1 - $1 ? $1 : 1 - $1) }' file
```

The expression `($1 > 0.5 ? 1 - $1 : $1)` would result in `1 - $1` if `$1 > 0.5`, otherwise it results in `$1`.  Likewise, `($1 < 1 - $1 ? $1 : 1 - $1)` would result in `$1` if `$1 < 1 - $1` is *true*, and in `1 - $1` otherwise.

For the given data, this would produce

```
0.0044
0.0018
0.3920
```